# How to get the value table td text value in this case

Tags: jquery

Please see this following fiddle .

https://jsfiddle.net/86gef8qa/2/

How can i get the value **FTSE** in this case ??

I have tried using

```
$("tbody tr").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find("td a").text());
});
```

could you please let me know how can i read the value

Comment: Please show relevant code in question itself. There is nothing shown in question relating to `FTSE` and we shouldn't have to go to a demo to understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eq()` to target the cell index:

```
$("tbody tr").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find("td:eq(3) a").text());
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/86gef8qa/6/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Well, is that how you have the HTML in your real app? You are missing the `<table></table>` wrap on the `tbody`, Chrome might allow that but it isn't valid HTML.

On the other hand, you have multiple `td` with `a` inside of it. So `$(this).find("td a")` is capturing multiple elements. And `text` needs to be called in a single one.

So I suggest to add a class to the column (`td`) that will hold FTSE, let's call it `ftse`, and change the query to `$(this).find("td.ftse > a")`. If you want to get all the text of all the `<a>`'s you might want to iterate over then inside the each you already have, like this:

```
$("tbody tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find("td > a").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Feel free to check the modified fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8p18amrr/)

Comment: thanks but ftse is a dynamic value and not known earlier

Comment: well i got your point , but this is not my code and cannot add ftse there

Comment: Then, how do you know that you want to get `FTSE`? Will it be based on the column #?